# INNODB FULLTEXT Index Performance and Optimization Strategy without Down Time

Tags: innodb, mysql-8.0

We have an INNODB table specifically for text searching which has a text column and a FULLTEXT index.  This table mostly get inserts and updates and almost no deletes in our model.  A typical table has less than 5 million rows and each row probably gets updated a few times when new before it ages into a stable state.

Over time we observe the query performance of this table degrades severely and an OPTIMIZE/ANALYZE is required which restores performance.  The problem we have is the database is basically unusable while this is running so we typically take the customer offline to do this.  Is there a way we can maintain the index health over time without customer down time?

Based on the docs at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-optimize I was hoping I could enable **innodb_optimize_fulltext_only** and run OPTIMIZE on the table in manageable blocks.  However in my testing I do not think that is the same as rebuilding the entire index.

Is there a strategy for zero down time index maintenance on a large FULLTEXT index like this with INNODB?

Comment: "gets updated a few times when new before it ages into a stable state" -- I don't understand; please elaborate.

Comment: Our customers write reports and new reports tend to get revised a few times during reviews when they are new.  We write text searchable data from reports to this table to facilitate free text searching.  So when new reports are written a new row is written to this table and then as the record gets revised we update the row in the text searching table.  So, the general pattern is a new row is added to the table for each new record in the system and it usually gets updated a couple times and then becomes stops changing.  I wanted to mention that as a possible reason for needing maintenance.